# Hadoop Hive equivalent of Python regex

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I have some text I need to parse in hadoop. I'm using Hive's to do so. I believe that Hive uses java regex.
I had written a Python regex that would accomplish the job.
Here's an example. I want to capture the value of a certain tag hidden in a blob of text.
blob:

```
eufebuWT.tz=12&ufdneuhnf
```

Python regex:

```
a=re.search(r'(?s)(?<=WT.tz=).+?(?=(&|$))'
a.group()
>12
```

If I plug that in Hive's regexp_extract() I get an error. How could that be translated in a Java compatible regex?

Comment: I suppose `WT[.]tz=([^&]+)` is a more effecient solution if you can access capture groups. What is your example string?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, just missing an escape.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to grab the `12` value in the input string (I assume that from the regex you have), you'd better use a negated character class `[^&]` that matches *any character (even a newline, thus, no need in `(?s)`) other than a `&`.

```
(?<=WT[.]tz=)[^&]+
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nU4qI9/1). Note that a capturing group based solution is best here:

```
WT[.]tz([^&]+)
```

However, it depends on what is easier for you to implement in Hadoop.

If you still need to know if it is the end of the string or not, keep the capturing group at the end:

```
(?<=WT[.]tz=)[^&]+($|&)
```

I wrap the dot into a character class so that it was treated as a literal period, not *any-character-but-a-newline* subpattern.